# if $n\ge4$ then there exists a prime $p$ s.t. $n=p\cdot2^{k}+a$ where $k \ge 1$, $a<2^{k}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If $n$ is a positive integer $\ge4$ then there exists a prime $p$ such that $n=p\cdot2^{k}+a$ where $k \ge 1$, $a<2^{k}$.

For example:

$333 = 41\cdot2^3 + 5$

$461 = 3\cdot2^7 + 77$

Work-in-Progress Proof:

Select $k$ so that $2^k \le n$ and $2^{k+1} > n$, i.e. $2^k * 2 > n$.

Divide $n$ by $2^k$ so that $n = 2^k + a$, $a < 2^k$ by the division algorithm.

So $n = 2*2^{k-1} + a$, 2 is prime ($p=2$), $k \ge 1$, and $a < 2^k$.

Comment: On what grounds do you think this is true?

Comment: @Gerry I have verified it for 4 <= n <= 1000000.

Comment: divide $n$ by $2$ until you get a quotient of $2$ or $3$.

Comment: Is it true for 30?

Comment: @hhsaffar: yes, 30 = 7*2^2 + 2, 30 = 3*2^3 + 6.

Comment: @mercio. I think your comment proves the conjecture. The conjecture appears to be a rewording of the division algorithm. I am still curious as to why there often exist p > 3.

Comment: You can't select $k$ for $n=2^m$ for some $m$, in your proof.

Comment: And what you've proven is $n=2^k + a$, not $n = p\cdot 2^k + a$

Comment: @ZaferSernikli I can always select $k$ so that $2^k < n$ and $2^{k+1} \ge n$. Agree?

Comment: @Jason Of course, but it says $2^k < n$ and $2^{k+1}>n$

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry: I'm trying to add a comment, but I can't do it.

I do not know if I misunderstood something:
if $n\geq 4$ is odd then $\exists ! k,\ k\in \mathbb N$ such that $2^k< n < 2^{k+1} $. This means $n= 2^k + a$ with $a < 2^k$ (if not we will have $n\geq 2^{k=1}$). For the even case, we can use a really similar line of reasoning ($n=2^{k_n}\cdot m$ with $m$ odd). 
In particular, in each case, we have $p=1$.

Comment: Please explain a little more the even case.

Comment: $n=2^{k_n}\cdot m$ with $m$ odd. So we know that $m=2^{k_m}+a_m$ with $a_m< 2^{k_n}$. Define $a_n= 2^{k_n}\cdot a_m$. We have that $a_n< 2^{k_n+k_m}$ and $n=2^{k_n+k_m}+ a_n$.

Comment: Sorry, I made a typo mistake: $a_m< 2^{k_m}$.

Comment: Ok thanks, there is still a problem, is $1$ a prime number...

Comment: No it is not a real problen. Can you see it? HINT: if $a<2^{k-1}$ no problem, if $2^{k-1}\leq a < 2^{k}$ reuse the same construction.